# Change Label to Textbox in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have a support application in VB6. It has a form with all Label fields to show data.The requirement is change all the Labels to Textbox's in the form.

I could not see any source code to do it easily for all the controls in the form.
What is the best alternative to do this other than manually changing every label to textbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change it by editing the .frm file for the form. You cannot do this in the Visual Basic IDE you will need to use a text editor. A simple label looks like this:

```
   Begin VB.Label Label1 
      BackStyle       =   0  'Transparent
      Caption         =   "Existing Designs:"
      Height          =   255
      Left            =   240
      TabIndex        =   4
      Top             =   120
      Width           =   2175
   End
```

An edit box like:

```
   Begin VB.TextBox CardName 
      Text            =   "Existing Designs:"
      Height          =   285
      Left            =   240
      TabIndex        =   0
      Top             =   4320
      Width           =   6375
   End
```

You could easily convert one type of control to another with a few search and replaces.

Comment: +1 Watch out for properties that reference the FRX. Try to understand what every property means in the label definitions, before you delete / adapt it.

Comment: Thanks Rob.I was not able to see the control definitions in VB6.0 editor.When I opened the .frm file in Notepad++ , I can see the control definitions.

Comment: Yes @RaviShankarKota you can only see them in a text editor - I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert.
   Because both of these are objects have some data, methods and properties which are different with respect to each other.

Comment: You are right Divyam.Property like Caption is available for Label but not textbox.But still I can modify frm file and change control to textbox.I can make necessary changes in code that suits Textbox which is more time saving.